# why inheritance doesn't work well for this

Tags: python, enums

1、I first used Python version 2.7, and through pip installed `enum` module.

```
from enum import Enum

class Format(Enum):
    json = 0
    other = 1
    @staticmethod
    def exist(ele):
        if Format.__members__.has_key(ele):
            return True
        return False

class Weather(Enum):
    good = 0
    bad = 1
    @staticmethod
    def exist(ele):
        if Weather.__members__.has_key(ele):
            return True
        return False

Format.exist('json')
```

Which works well, but I want to improve the code.

2、So I thought a better way might be like this:

```
from enum import Enum

class BEnum(Enum):
    @staticmethod
    def exist(ele):
        if BEnum.__members__.has_key(ele)                   
            return True
        return False

class Format(Enum):
    json = 0
    other = 1

class Weather(Enum):
    good = 0
    bad = 1

Format.exist('json')
```

However this results in an error, because `BEnum.__members__` is a class variable.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three things you need to do here. First, you need to make `BEnum` inherit from `Enum`:

```
class BEnum(Enum):
```

Next, you need to make `BEnum.exist` a class method:

```
    @classmethod
    def exist(cls,ele):
        return cls.__members__.has_key(ele)
```

Finally, you need to have `Format` and `Weather` inherit from `BEnum`:

```
class Format(BEnum):

class Weather(BEnum):
```

With `exist` being a static method, it can only operate on a specific class, regardless of the class that it is called from. By making it a class method, the class it is called from is passed automatically as the first argument (`cls`), and can be used for member access.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669524/2508324) is a great description about the differences between static and class methods.

Comment: sorry, I first write code have same bugs, I have modify it.